# multiple websocket servers in rust

Tags: rust, websocket

I referred [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-build-a-websocket-server-with-rust/) and also tried [tungstenite library](https://crates.io/crates/tungstenite). But I was able to run only one server at a time, it captured whole thread.

I tried running multiple servers on different thread but that never listen anything and just exit the program.

Is there anyway that I can run multiple WebSocket servers on different ports, and create, destroy a server in runtime?

Edit: If I run a server on main thread and another one on other thread, it works, looks like I'd have to keep  main thread busy somehow.. but is there any better way?

here's some example code:

it uses:

```
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::thread::spawn;
use tungstenite::accept;
```

this is the normal code that blocks the main thread

```
let server = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:9002").expect("err: ");
        for stream in server.incoming() {
            spawn(move || {
                let mut websocket = accept(stream.unwrap()).unwrap();
                loop {
                    let msg = websocket.read_message().unwrap();

                    println!("{}", msg);

                    // We do not want to send back ping/pong messages.
                    if msg.is_binary() || msg.is_text() {
                        websocket.write_message(msg).unwrap();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

here's the code with thread:

```
spawn(|| {
        let server = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:9001").expect("err: ");
        for stream in server.incoming() {
            spawn(move || {
                let mut websocket = accept(stream.unwrap()).unwrap();
                loop {
                    let msg = websocket.read_message().unwrap();

                    println!("{}", msg);

                    // We do not want to send back ping/pong messages.
                    if msg.is_binary() || msg.is_text() {
                        websocket.write_message(msg).unwrap();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

but the above code needs the main thread to run somehow, I'm indeed able to run multiple servers on different threads but need something to occupy main thread.

Comment: Could you include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question? The linked blog post is quite long, it would be great for the users to work off of your own minimal code that demonstrates your problems.

Comment: @justinas added sample code

Comment: These are not reproducible examples - we do not know what crates and modules are imported, where things like `spawn` and `accept` come from, etc.

Comment: There is also a [tokio-tungstenite](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-tungstenite) crate to write an async server.

Comment: @rodrigo do you have any docs link for tokio-tungstenite?

Comment: @Sandip: The official docs are [here](https://docs.rs/tokio-tungstenite/0.17.2/tokio_tungstenite/), naturally. Take also a look to the [examples](https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite/tree/master/examples) in the source code repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust programs terminate when the end of `main()` is reached. What you need to do is wait until your secondary threads have finished.

`std::thread::spawn` returns a [JoinHandle](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html), which has a [join](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join) method which does exactly that - it waits (blocks) until the thread that the handle refers to finishes, and returns an error if the thread panicked.

So, to keep your program alive as long as any threads are running, you need to collect all of these handles, and `join()` them one by one. Unlike a busy-loop, this will not waste CPU resources unnecessarily.

```rust
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::thread::spawn;
use tungstenite::accept;

fn main() {
    let mut handles = vec![];

    // Spawn 3 identical servers on ports 9001, 9002, 9003
    for i in 1..=3 {
        let handle = spawn(move || {
            let server = TcpListener::bind(("127.0.0.1", 9000 + i)).expect("err: ");
            for stream in server.incoming() {
                spawn(move || {
                    let mut websocket = accept(stream.unwrap()).unwrap();
                    loop {
                        let msg = websocket.read_message().unwrap();

                        println!("{}", msg);

                        // We do not want to send back ping/pong messages.
                        if msg.is_binary() || msg.is_text() {
                            websocket.write_message(msg).unwrap();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    // Wait for each thread to finish before exiting
    for handle in handles {
        if let Err(e) = handle.join() {
            eprintln!("{:?}", e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do all the work in a thread (or threads) and the main thread has nothing to do, usually it is set to wait (`join`) that thread.

This has the additional advantage that if your secondary thread finishes or panics, then your program will also finish. Or you can wrap the whole *create-thread/join-thread* in a loop and make it more resilient:

```
fn main() {
    loop {
        let th = std::thread::spawn(|| {
            // Do the real work here
            std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
            panic!("oh!");
        });
        if let Err(e) = th.join() {
            eprintln!("Thread panic: {:?}", e)
        }
    }
}
```

Link to [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8c964e43256c053157585b3edd8be1c), I've changed to the loop into a `for _ in ..3` because playgrond does not like infinite loops.

Comment: This is technically correct, but will not achieve the effect OP wants - this spawns one thread at a time, and waits for it to finish before spawning another one, essentially preventing any concurrency. It seems like OP wants to run several servers in parallel.

Comment: @justinas I think that is not so. You spawn a single thread that listens for connections, that in turn spawns a new thread per connection. The main thread waits for the listening thread only, and all the connections are run in parallel, only the listening is serialized, but that should not be an issue in a normal server.

Comment: Yes, in a single (non-async) server your suggestion would make sense: a listener thread + one thread per client. However, the OP specifically stated they want to run multiple *servers*: "Is there anyway that I can run multiple WebSocket servers on different ports, and create, destroy a server [at] runtime?"

Comment: Yes, but with this we can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74073978/13327203) but can't achieve what I want